# Mongoose: how to count a number of schema that other schema refers to?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

As I wrote above, I have a schema which refers to another different schema. These are:

```
exports.Policies = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   description: String,
   exploits: [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'exploit', required: true} ]
});
exports.exploit = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    type: String,
    required: [String]
});
```

What I want to do is just know how many values have 'exploits' array as a field inside of the response, is this possible? In sql I have to write only "count(field)" and making a "group by", how might I do this?

An example:

```
{
    "name" : "mmmmmm",
    "description" : "jjjj",
    "_id" : ObjectId("533721b91a985b883399cdc2"),
    "n_exploits" : 2 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is just the [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator if you have no need to filter array content.

Assuming that you have a model to your schema that is named "policies" then the following is achieved through use of [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```
policies.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$exploits" }
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "count": { "sum": 1 }
     }}
],function(err,doc) {

});
```

So this works by unwinding the array and then counting the number of elements that are produced when you re-group.

In future releases there is a a new [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator so you can skip those stages and just use project:

```
policies.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
       "count": { "$size": "$exploits" }
    }}
],function(err,doc) {

});
```

Or otherwise use that with [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to add up arrays across documents.

But for now you do the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operations. Working inside the mongodb engine is typically done in "native" code and the JavaScript operators are not available. But also as native code these operators work very fast.

Also see the [**aggregation operator reference**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) for other things you may wish to do.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried searching this before posting here? A simple google search with words "mongodb count group by" gives kind of a lot of results, which are not only telling you that you have too look into [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/), but also give you some examples even on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13240039/1090562) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19909105/1090562).

Comment: Of course I did, but to be honest I didn't write "group by" on my search. I read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451575/how-to-count-records-with-one-distinct-field-in-mongoose But mongoose showed me an error. I'm going to check your links. Thank you for your reply

Comment: @Daniel976034 first try to come up with a valid mongodb way and only then look how to translate it to mongoose.

Comment: Ok, got it. But I have a question. Policies.exploits is an array, how can i get the number of the items? Because if i write "$exploits.length" in a "$group" statement, it doesn't work.